# Is there a way to approximately estimate how long DTW distance matrix calculation will take?

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, dtw

I have a relatively large time-series data with 10000 observations (rows) and 200 variables (columns) in an `R` `dataframe`. I want to run a clustering algorithm on my data, specifically Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) based hierarchical clustering.

Before running hierarchical clustering, I need to calculate distance matrix. The way I implement it in `R` is as follows:

```
library(dtw)
d = dist(df, method = "DTW") # df is my data (10000 by 200)
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to approximately estimate how long this calculation will take before running the code. This would help me decide whether it is worth trying it out.

P.S. I ran the code but after several minutes I had to stop it as I had no idea how long it would take (minutes, hours, days etc.)

Comment: Not necessarily the most elegant solution, but just start with a very tine data set, w.g 10 rows/columns. Then add rows, then add columns. Each timw you compute the time it takes and then you have a more or less reliable estimate of how long it would take with a larger data set.

Comment: You may have a look here <https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/5-ways-to-measure-running-time-of-r-code/>

Comment: Are you sure your problem definition makes sense? That code will try to calculate a 10,000 x 10,000 matrix, I doubt that fits in memory at all. On the other hand, you could try extrapolating from [these experiments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/timing-experiments.html), although those use a different distance implementation, not the one from the `dtw` package.